# True anatomical/physiological explanation for "metaphysis" etymology

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy, etymology

The anatomy textbook<sup>1</sup> I use for my students states that the prefix *meta-* means "between:"

> The metaphyses (me-TAF-i-sez; ***meta* = between**; singular is *metaphysis*) **are the regions between the diaphysis and the epiphysis**.   [*my emphasis added*]

This sounds reasonable given the explanation. However, I have never seen *meta*- applied in this manner; more generally, the suffix *meta*- usually seems to refer to "after."

In fact, [Dr. Toby Arnold's Glossary of Anatomy](https://anatomy.usyd.edu.au/glossary/glossary.cgi?page=m) provides the following etymology of the word metaphysis:

> metaphysis: Greek **meta = after**, and physis = growth; hence, **the end of the shaft** of a bone alongside the epiphysial or growth cartilage  *[again, my emphasis added]*

The latter explanation is somewhat underwhelming, but the etymological usage fits more with my prior experience with *meta*-.

So, which is it?

**Can someone find a reputable source *definitively* indicating a clear *anatomical/physiological* explanation for why *meta-* was used in the case of "metaphysis"?**

- [A webpage on EnglishLearner.com](https://www.englishlearner.com/dictionary/metaphysis#Etymology_n) reports that our earliest usage of the term "metaphysis" came from an obstetrician named William Dorland (1864–1956) in the early 20th century. I couldn;t find additional info.

---

<sup>1. Tortora, G. J. and B. Derrickson. 2014. *Principles of Anatomy & Physiology*, 14th edition. John Wiley & Sons, Inc., USA.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

**meta-:**

> word-forming element of Greek origin meaning 1. "after, behind; among,
>   between," 2. "changed, altered," 3. "higher, beyond;" from Greek meta (prep.) "in the midst of; in common with; by means of;
>   between; in pursuit or quest of; after, next after, behind," in
>   compounds most often meaning "change" of place, condition, etc. This
>   is from PIE *me- "in the middle" (source also of German mit, Gothic
>   miþ, Old English mið "with, together with, among"). Notion of
>   "changing places with" probably led to senses "change of place, order,
>   or nature," which was a principal meaning of the Greek word when used
>   as a prefix (but also denoting "community, participation; in common
>   with; pursuing"). *([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/meta-))*

**physis:**

> The growth plate, or physis, is the translucent, cartilaginous disc
>   separating the epiphysis from the metaphysis and is responsible for
>   longitudinal growth of long bones. *([The Royal's Children Hospital Melbourne](https://www.rch.org.au/fracture-education/growth_plate_injuries/Physeal_growth_plate_injuries/))*

*Anatomically and physiologically,* meta- in metaphysis means **next after** physis (growth plate or epiphyseal plate) and refers to the **changing** (growing) part, which is in between the non-growing parts of a long bone (diaphysis and epiphysis):

> The metaphysis is the wider portion of a long bone *adjacent* to the
>   epiphyseal plate. It is this part of the bone that grows during
>   childhood; as it grows, it ossifies *near the diaphysis and the
>   epiphyses.* *([Orthopaedicsone](https://www.orthopaedicsone.com/display/Main/Metaphysis))*

[image]

*Picture: Parts of the bone ([Radiopedia](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/physis), Creative Commons license)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Jan. I was surprised to see *meta* referring to "between", but I now know it's not unprecedented. A comment on your last point though... So *-physis* is actually the part of the word referring to "growing" (changing), but you got me to thinking: the epiphyseal plate (associated with the metaphysis) is all about growing the bone's length (i.e., "beyond"), so I wonder if this is the physiological explanation for the etymology??

Comment: Again, I appreciate you finding the linguistic source, but could your try to provide a source that supports your last paragraph directly? Makes sense to me too, but I'm curious to see a reputable indication of Dorland's reasoning  (or modern physiological interpretation thereof)

Comment: consider metaphase, between-phase.

Comment: @theforestecologist, I made it simpler: anatomically and physiologically, meta- in metaphysis means "next after" physis and "between" diaphysis and epiphysis.

Comment: @John duhhh. Wow, you just made me realize I've explored this very question before but focused on metaphase previously. Of course, meta is between in that context! Oy I knew that! (I need more sleep before I post questions :p). Thanks, Jan, for the updates!

Answer (score -1):

Bones grow for a long time.(teenage? adolescence?)
what does the suffix "-physis" mean? "Growth", so bone is longer and longer. We know the vital part of bone is metaphysis, but let's suppose that we are ingorant, simply observing that the bone shaft growing after the LINE between the bone shaft and "骺".
(both ends of bones are called “骺” in Chinese)

Bone's length is the diaphysis itself, growing INSIDE it.
Bone's length is following the metaphysis, growing AFTER it.
Bone's length is not influenced epiphysis (both ends of bones are called “骺” in Chinese), growing BELOW it, and “骺” is OVER the shaft.

This is why we use prefixes "dia-" "meta-" and "epi-", because this is how the components relate to the length.